# How do I use wildcards, RegEx or Search() within Mixpanel's Javascript query language call?

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I'm using Mixpanel JQL and struggling to search using wildcards within the JQL/Javascript call. I'm trying to filter any phone numbers starting with '+52'. 
I tried using RegEx, search() but as I'm clueless about Javascript nothing seems to work.
How do I filter for all strings starting with '52+'?

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: '2020-01-01',
    to_date:   '2020-12-31'
   }).filter(function(event)
   {return event.properties.$phone!='+5211111111' && event.properties.$phone!='+52222222222'   })
}
```

Comment: Try `event.properties.phone.startsWith('+52')`. Also your code seems to have some syntax errors.

Comment: @Mingwei-Samuel 
Sadly startsWith()  does not seem to be supported. Error returned is: 
    s.Recv failed: rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = Uncaught exception TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
   {return event.properties.$phone.startsWith('+52') })
                                   ^

Stack trace:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:7:36

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with .indexOf():

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: "2020-01-01",
    to_date: "2020-01-30"
  })
  .filter(function(event){ return event.properties.$phone.indexOf("+52") !== -1 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a regex test

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: "2020-01-01",
    to_date: "2020-01-30"
  })
  .filter(function(event){ return /^(?!\+52)/.test(event.properties.$phone) });
}
```